# Numpy delete multiple rows matching criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of folowing structure

```
sb = np.genfromtxt(open('HomePage/TodayList.txt', 'rb'),
                   delimiter=',', skiprows=0,
                   dtype=[('DataBase', np.str_, 16), ('Mode', np.str_, 16),
                          ('SMB', np.str_, 16),('Desc', np.str_, 128), 
                          ('Res', np.str_, 16), ('RightCnt', np.float64), 
                          ('PercentCnt', np.float64), ('ModelType', np.float64)])
```

The 6th column `'PercentCnt'` which can be accessed by name `'PercentCnt'` contains numbers from 0 to 50
the 7th column `'ModelType'` contains numbers from 0 to 5 so i need to remove or delete array rows which match these criteria `'PercentCnt'<50` and `'ModelType'<2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all rows matching your criteria by use of a column-wise comparison for `PercentCnt` and `ModelType` and connection using [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). Doing that, you  actually copy all other rows rather than to delete the ones you wanted to get rid of, but the effect is the same.

```
sb = sb[np.logical_and(sb["PercentCnt"]>=50, sb["ModelType"]>=2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition

```
sb['PercentCnt'] >= 50
```

is the condition for *keeping* things on this column, and the condition

```
sb['ModelType'] >= 2
```

is the same for the other column.

You can combine these with [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
keep = np.logical_and(sb['PercentCnt'] >= 50, sb['ModelType'] >= 2)
```

Finally, just keep the rows you wish to keep:

```
sb[keep]
```